# How do I use a in clause 'in' a grails.gorm.DetachedCriteria?

Tags: grails, grails-orm, detachedcriteria

Is it possible to use an `'in'` criteria in a Grails DetachedCriteria?

This is what I have,

```
def query = new DetachedCriteria(DomainObject)

// list is actually built up from another query, 
// but for this example I will use a predefined list
query.where { 'in' 'id', [4L, 5L, 9L] }

def count = query.count()
```

What I am seeing is that the count, which you would expect to be 3, is actually just the entire DomainObject table.

How do I get this query to work?

Comment: Try assigning the result of where to query: `query = query.where { 'in' 'id', [4L, 5L, 9L] }`

Comment: @elias, doh, that's totally it, want to post that an answer so I can give you credit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try assigning the result of where to a query:

```
query = query.where { 'in' 'id', [4L, 5L, 9L] }
```

Comment: You can also write it as, `query = query.where { 'id' in [4L, 5L, 9L] }`, though I am not sure if that changes the performance of the query at all